# Rails - How to paginate json associations, using as_json include/methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a Post that has many Comments. I have something like this in my model

```
class Post < AR:Base
  ...

  PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES = [:id, :title]
  JSON_METHODS = [:comments]

  ...

  def as_json(options={})
    opts = {
      only: PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES,
      methods: JSON_METHODS
    }.merge(options){|k,o,n|o|n}
    super(opts)
  end
  ...
end
```

So in my controller I can just:

```
def show
  post = Post.find ...
  render json: { post: post }
end
```

JSON magically appears. The issue is when I have a lot of comments I want to paginate on. Also, the API is already in use, so people are using json[post][comments], otherwise i'd just add comments in like `{post:post, comments:comments}`, but that's a no-go.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699182/will-paginate-json-support

Comment: @dbugger Can you show me where that answers my question? I'm not seeing it.